# Memory order of an std::atomic_bool flag

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-model

I'm reading "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams and i came across this piece of code, a simple implementation of a threadpool.

```
class thread_pool
{
    std::atomic_bool done;
    thread_safe_queue<std::function<void()> > work_queue;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    join_threads joiner;

    void worker_thread()
    {
        while(!done) 
        {
            std::function<void()> task;
            if(work_queue.try_pop(task))            
            {
                task(); 
            }
            else
            {
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
       }
    }
    public:
    thread_pool():
        done(false),joiner(threads)
    {
        unsigned const thread_count=std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        try 
        {

           for(unsigned i=0;i<thread_count;++i)
           {
              threads.push_back(
                 std::thread(&thread_pool::worker_thread,this));
           } 
        }
        catch(...)
        {
           done=true;
           throw;
        }
     }

    ~thread_pool()
    {
        done=true;
    }

    template<typename FunctionType>
    void submit(FunctionType f)
    {
        work_queue.push(std::function<void()>(f));
    }
};
```

P.S. join_threads is a simple class that joins threads on destruction and
     thread_safe_queue is a ... thread safe queue!

My question is about the boolean flag **std::atomic_bool done**. I've read  that using the default assignment operator is the same of using the *sequentially-consistent memory ordering*.

done=true.   ->   done.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst)

Is it really necessary in this case? Wouldn't it be sufficient to use a       *release/acquiring ordering* or even a *relaxed* one?
The worker threads are just looping over the bool value and apparently there isn't any other memory access to synchronize with.

Am i over optimizing or do i miss something?

Comment: There isn't any other code in the destructor - why would the specific choice of memory order matter?

Comment: The threadpool constructor and destructor don't run on the same thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've misunderstood.  Sequentially-consistent access is more constrained than the minimum requirement.

In this case, the use of `std::atomic::operator=` has the advantage of simplicity (i.e. clearer code), and is unlikely to introduce any performance problems - particularly as, on most platforms, atomic booleans map to processor operations very closely.